# Chrome font not rendering properly after Ubuntu update

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've been running *Ubuntu 16.04* for a while now.

After a recent update, certain fonts are not displaying properly in **Chrome**.

See attached screenshot for reference.

*Firefox* has no issue displaying the same pages.

[image]

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the problem:

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and run it
2. Click on the Fonts menu
3. For the "Antialiasing" option, choose Grayscale or None
4. Restart Chrome

Comment: That worked, thanks!  If anyone is wondering, "Antialiasing" is an attempt to make the font smother.  Selecting "None" made the font look very jagged and blocky. Selecting "Grayscale" looked much better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04) it was the scale factor that was set to 0.91. Setting it to 1.00 solved the problem.
[Tweak config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNioO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option and restarting Chrome fixed the font issue for me.

1. Open Chrome Settings menu
2. Search for `Use hardware acceleration when available`
3. Turn off toggle button.
4. Click on the `Relaunch` button suddenly appeared in front of it.